# Using sx1276-Lora module with Raspberry

Tags: pi-3, spi

I'm trying to use Lora module with my Raspberry to be a gateway.

The nodes I use are Arduino with same Lora module and it works!

Source code I use is [Lora-Arduino](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/arduino-LoRa) and [node-sx127x](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/node-sx127x/).

Howerver there's some problem, the code both can run on my Pi3 but receive.js 
can not receive data from any Arduino-node.

The sender.js on Pi can send data to Arduino's receive code.

I have no idea what's the problem it is.

The Lora module I used are sx1276 with single channel and SPI interface.

Comment: where are you getting sender.js or recive.js from?

Comment: @MohammadAli The code is from "node-sx127x" on Github, install by npm and the example include "sender.js" and "receiver.js". The sender.js could send the data and receive by Arduino's with Lora module. But recevier.js running without error but can't receive.